# I want loop create grouped data based on Select2 data format

Tags: php, mysql, loops, jquery-select2

I want loop create grouped data based on select2 data format by HardwareTypeCode.

I can't figure out what to do with PHP.

**SQL Query:**

```
 SELECT historyhardwaretb.HardwareID,
    hardwaretb.HardwareCode,
    hardwaretb.IPAddress,
    hardwaretb.MacAddress,
    hardwaretypetb.HardwareTypeCode,
    historyhardwaretb.EmployeeID,
    historyhardwaretb.Description
    FROM historyhardwaretb
    INNER JOIN hardwaretb ON historyhardwaretb.HardwareID = hardwaretb.HardwareID
    INNER JOIN hardwaretypetb ON hardwaretb.HardwareTypeID = hardwaretypetb.HardwareTypeID
```

**PHP:**

```
while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
   $jsonGroup[$i]['text'] = $row['HardwareTypeCode'];
}
```

**Expected select2 grouped data format result:**

```
{
  "jsonGroup": [
    { 
      "text": "PC", 
      "children" : [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "text": "Option 1.1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "text": "Option 1.2"
        }
      ]
    },
    { 
      "text": "NB", 
      "children" : [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "text": "Option 2.1"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "text": "Option 2.2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "pagination": {
    "more": true
  }
}
```

**Reference:**
https://select2.org/data-sources/formats#grouped-data